# Delegation from ContainerView to parent ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, delegation

I have the following setup:

StartViewController has a ContainerView that contains ContainerViewController

I try to find a way to hidden an element in StartViewController after a task is performed in ContainerViewController.

For this I try to use delegation method like this:

**StartViewController**

```
class StartViewController: UIViewController, showBannerAdDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        bannerView.hidden = false
    }

    func bannerAdHidden(status: Bool) {
        bannerView.hidden = status
    }

}
```

**ContainerViewController**

```
protocol showBannerAdDelegate: class {
    func bannerAdHidden(status: Bool)
}

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: showBannerAdDelegate! = nil

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate.bannerAdHidden(true)
    }

}
```

If I presented the ContainerViewController I could do in prepareForSegue

```
let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! ContainerViewController
destination.delegate = self
```

But in this case both View Controller are always present.

What code should I add to the View Controller to make it work?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one of the view controllers is inside a container view then it is loaded with an embed segue, which fires when the containing view controller is first loaded. The `prepareForSegue` method still gets called, so you can set up a delegate exactly as you've described. I always thought embed segues were a little odd (it's not really a segue, more like loading a child view controller) but that's how it works.